# reconciling data from two excel sheets

Tags: excel

I have two sheets I am trying to reconcile. The first sheet contains a list of partner organizations in Column A, the type of organization in Column B, and what type of audience the organization reaches in Column C. The second sheet contains contact info for each partner organization, with multiple contacts listed for each organization. Column A in the first sheet matches Column A in the second sheet (except for the fact that some of the partner organizations are listed multiple times in the second sheet). I need to populate the type of organization (column B) and type of audience (column C) from the first sheet into the second sheet. What's the best way to accomplish this?
I am thinking V lookup but I am not sure how to proceed with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Vlookup will do! You may require to adjust the cell reference and sheet name accordingly.!

[image]